# Select column header(s) in SQL where count of value is 1

Tags: sql, ssms

I'm trying to return the column headers for columns of data in which the count of the value is one.

I've attached some sample data below, and want my query to return column headers such as '**FinalCompare**', but not '**BeginCompare**'

I should point out that in my actual dataset, there is many more than one column that I'm trying to return. (i.e. there will be many more 'Final Compare' columns)

```
IFinal  | UFinal  | FinalCompare |     IBegin  | UBegin  | BeginCompare |
 NULL   | NULL    | Y            |      NULL   | 0       | N            |
 NULL   | NULL    | Y            |      NULL   | NULL    | Y            |
 NULL   | NULL    | Y            |      NULL   | NULL    | Y            |
 NULL   | NULL    | Y            |      NULL   | 1       | N            |
 NULL   | NULL    | Y            |      NULL   | NULL    | Y            |
 NULL   | NULL    | Y            |      NULL   | NULL    | Y            |
 NULL   | NULL    | Y            |      NULL   | NULL    | Y            |
```

Is this a simple way to do this in SQL?

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way, but you have to list each column.  Something like:

```
select ( (case when min(FinalCompare) = max(FinalCompare) then 'FinalCompare;' else '' end) ||
         (case when min(BeginCompare) = max(BeginCompare) then 'BeginCompare;' else '' end)
       ) as columns_with_one_value
from t;
```

You need to list each column as a separate `case` expression.  Note that this compares `min()` and `max()`, because that is usually cheaper than `count(distinct)`.